# Templates for Developing Web Page

Tags: python, html, web

I am quite new to coding, and have limited experience with HTML and Python. I would like to develop a web page for personal use, and I thought it might be easier to starter with a template and customize it from there. Can anyone recommend a place to find some free templates, or know a good place to start looking?

Comment: This is off-topic. Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I learned how with Flask using this [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). It's for creating a blog, but you can apply the concepts to other types of websites.

It is time consuming and will feel cumbersome at first, but it teaches you some extra things you need to know if you want the web page to be interactive, store data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Start Bootstrap is a great starting place! https://startbootstrap.com/ It has free, open source templates that you can use and let you become more comfortable with bootstrap.

Although I do recommend going through W3 tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/html/ and really familiarizing yourself with HTML and CSS if web development is of interest to you.